# Аллофоны фонем, помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: фонетика, фонология

Затранскрибируйте слова; определите, вариантами (аллофонами) каких фонем являются в них гласные и согласные звуки.

Дробь, оженить, просьба

Comment: Представьте свой вариант. аллофон (от греч. allos — другой + phone — звук). Конкретная реализация фонемы. Аллофоны — это группа звуков, в которых проявляется данная фонема в зависимости от места в слове, соседства с другими звуками, ударяемости или безударности гласного и т. д. Так, фонема <а> имеет следующие аллофоны: (а) — в слове пат, (а·) — в слове мать, (•а) — в слове пятый, (a) — в слове пять, (A) — в слове патрон, (иe) — в слове пятак, (ъ) — в слове патриот, (ь) — в слове пятерик. см. также вариант фонемы.

Comment: Уважаемая Татьяна, а почему Вы в одном случае используете слово "ударяемости", а в другом "ударности" (безударности)?

Comment: потому что ударность и ударяемость - одно и то же, термины используются как синонимы

Answer (score 2):

Дробь, оженить, просьба

[Дроп’] аллофон  [д°]-фонема <д>(°перед огубленным гласным о)  ; [р°] - <р> ; [о•] - <о> (•перед мягким согл.) ; [п’]- <б’>

[Λжыэнит‘] [Λ ] - <о>;  [ж] - <ж>;  - [ыэ] -<е>;   [н’] - <н>; [•и] - <и>;  [т‘] - <т’>;

[проз‘бъ]  [п°] - <п>;  [р°]  - <р>;  [о•]  - <о>;   [з’] = <с’>; [б] -  <б >;  [ъ] - <а>
http://www.lib.tpu.ru/fulltext/m/2011/IvanovaLS_VasilyevaSL/Index/2/variation.html

Comment: От Игоря сообщение.====== Спасибо, Людмила за ответ! Мне казалось, что "ударность" и "ударяемость" - формы отглагольных прилагательных (если таковые существуют в русском языке, простите - не филолог), различающие единичный и повторяющийся процессы.